# Horizontal Menu bar stretching width of web page using CSS

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

Horizontal menu bar that will automatically stretch to the width of a web page. How might this be achieved using css?

Have just added the following css to bootstrap CSS:

```
ul.dropdown-menu li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

This makes drop-menu horizontal how do I make drop menus stretch width of page?
Setting width:100% does not work.

See:
http://jsfiddle.net/aBJVs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.dropdown-menu {
position: fixed;
top:40px;
left: 0;
width:100%;
z-index: 1000;
//etc
}
.dropdown-menu li {
display: inline-block; 
}
```

This will make your new div start on the left side of the screen and take the whole browser width.

Comment: I see where you are going with "fixed" but it doesn't solve the problem. See the jsfiddle link.

Comment: Check this [http://jsfiddle.net/aBJVs/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/aBJVs/1/), is this not as you wish?

Comment: Not quite. The menu items need to be horizontal too. I used display:inline-block for this.

Comment: Ok, i try to understand what you need. Is this - [http://jsfiddle.net/aBJVs/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/aBJVs/2/) - the result you expect?